# How text file can be converted to arff file?

Tags: java

I am trying to convert a text file into an ARFF (Attribute Relation File Format) file. Below are the structure of file that is required.

```
@relation data1
@attribute f1 numeric
@attribute f2 numeric
@attribute f3 numeric
@attribute f4 numeric
@attribute f5 numeric
@attribute f6 numeric
@attribute class {1,2}


@DATA
-0.32,-0.63,-0.46,-0.49,-0.23,-0.16,1
-0.51,-0.45,-0.16,-0.3,-0.22,0.43,2
    ....
```

so far I use the following code but it did not give me the same exact structure of arff file

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));
String toWrite = "";
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    toWrite += line;
   // System.out.println(toWrite);
}
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("aa1.arff",true);
fw.write(toWrite);
fw.close();
```

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

i **strongly guess** that you are missing line breaks...

the bufferedReader creates a `String` for each line you read, but the linebreak itself is lost.

> BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));

so when you write that content again back into the file you should use either a `BufferedWriter`and write line by line. Or, just as you do, write 'en bloc', but then you have to add a lineBreak manually.

```
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    //toWrite += line; //line break is no more in the destination
    toWrite = toWrite + line + "\n"; //but here you go...
}
```

note - no encoding issues have been considered using this answer!